# Нужна помощь в реализации присвоения переменным данных из текстового файла C#

Tags: c#

Пишу лабу по ООП, нужно сделать класс треугольник, дочерний класс равносторонний треугольник и у каждого из них свои методы. Вроде ничего сложного, все сделал, но значения сторон должно браться из текстового файла, в этом и проблема, помогите реализовать пожалуйста. Вот код класса треугольник:

```
public class Triangle
{
    //стороны треугольника
    public double FirstSide { get; set; }
    public double SecondSide { get; set; }
    public double ThirdSide { get; set; }
    //площадь
    public double Square { get; set; }
    //статические переменные для поиска средней площади
    public static double sum = 0;
    public static double counter = 0;
    //конструктор
    public Triangle(double firstSide, double secondSide, double thirdSide)
    {
        this.FirstSide = firstSide;
        this.SecondSide = secondSide;
        this.ThirdSide = thirdSide;
    }
    //метод проверяющий существует ли даннный треугольник
    public virtual void IsExist()
    {
        if (FirstSide > SecondSide + ThirdSide || SecondSide > FirstSide + ThirdSide || ThirdSide > FirstSide + SecondSide)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Такой треугольник не существует!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //поиск полупериметра
            double halfSquare = (FirstSide + SecondSide + ThirdSide) / 2;
            //поиск площади
            Square = Math.Sqrt(halfSquare * (halfSquare - FirstSide) * (halfSquare - SecondSide) * (halfSquare - ThirdSide));
            //ищем суммарную площадь
            sum += Square;
            //наращиваем кол-во треугольников
            counter++;
        }
    }
    //метод для перегрузки отображающий данные о треугольнике
    public virtual void Display()
    {
        //вывод данных на экран
        Console.WriteLine("Первая сторона = {0}, Вторая сторона = {1}, Третья сторона = {2}, Площадь = {3}, Периметр = {4}", FirstSide, SecondSide, ThirdSide, Square, FirstSide + SecondSide + ThirdSide);
    }
}
```

И вот код класса Main, и как я присваиваю сторонам значения:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //создаем три трегуольника, проверяем могут ли такие существовать,
        //результат выводим на экран
        Triangle first = new Triangle(2, 3, 4);
        first.IsExist();
        first.Display();
        Triangle second = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);
        second.IsExist();
        second.Display();
        Triangle third = new Triangle(5, 6, 7);
        third.IsExist();
        third.Display();
        //находим среднюю площадь треугольников
        double middleSquare = Triangle.sum / Triangle.counter;
        Console.WriteLine("Средняя площадь треугольника = {0}",middleSquare);
        Console.WriteLine("=======================================================================================================================");
        //создаем равносторонние треугольники
        EquilateralTriangle fourth = new EquilateralTriangle(3, 3, 3);
        fourth.IsExist();
        fourth.Display();
        EquilateralTriangle fifth = new EquilateralTriangle(4, 4, 4);
        fifth.IsExist();
        fifth.Display();
        EquilateralTriangle sixth = new EquilateralTriangle(5, 5, 5);
        sixth.IsExist();
        sixth.Display();
        //вывод самую большую площадь из равносторонних треугольников
        Console.WriteLine("Самая большая площадь = {0}", EquilateralTriangle.biggestSquare);
        Console.ReadKey();
        /*

            string path = @"D:\triangles.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
        {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                int[] arr = new int[3];
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    if (line[i] != ' ')
                    {
                        arr[i] = line[i];
                        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
                    }
                }
        }
        */
    }
```

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Вы [считать из файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB) не можете или считанную [строку в число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%B2+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) преобразовать? Что вы вообще пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: Для меня тема с чтением из файлом новая и непонятная, пробовал освоить но не получилось. Даже не представляю как это сделать.

Comment: что конкретно пробовали? Покажите код, что пробовали. Что в нем не получилось?

Comment: @tym32167 я хотел перебрать строку, и посимвольно занести в массив, и потом по индексам передать значения свойствам. Код указал в методе Main. Работает некорректно.

Comment: Доп код вставляйте в вопрос, в комментах его читать невозможно. Ну, вот вы считали строку из файла, что в этой строке? 3 числа разделенных пробелами? Числа целые или с плавающей точкой?

Comment: @tym32167 код добавил как комментарий, в текстовом файле числа 5,6,7 разделенные пробелом. В консоли выводиться лишь число 53

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93739/discussion-between-artemonthehuman-and-tym32167).